# How can I run DBT jobs with AWS Managed Airflow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, dbt, mwaa

I wanted to know, how I can run my DBT jobs with AWS Managed Airflow.

I have created an environment in AWS for testing followed this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67838522/how-to-use-dbt-with-aws-managed-airflow) they are failing.

Also I have uploaded **requirements.txt** in S3 along with **plugins.zip**

Content of plugins.zip

- dbt.py
- env_var_plugin.py

env_var_plugin.py

[image]

dbt.py
[image]

requirements.txt

[image]

Also uploaded my dag file S3 in Dags/ folder

Comment: Could you give more details as to what exactly is failing, what's the error message?

Comment: logs are not coming in Amazon MWAA